# Проблема с отступами css

Tags: css, css3

В одном браузере вид чата вот такой: картинка #1. Хотя должен быть как на картинке #2. Из-за чего такое выходит понять не могу. Кто-нибудь знает как решить это БЕЗ обозначения max-height (max-block-size) да и вообще без высоты, ведь высота блоком с тестом должна контролироваться её контентом.

На других фото есть дополнительная информация о блоках.

Код этого блока с сообщениями:

```css
.messages-container {
                            @include scrollbar(vw(5px), rgba(white, 0.05), #424549);
                            padding: vw(20px);
                            overflow: auto;

                            .message-block {
                                margin-top: vw(20px);
                                border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(white, 0.1);

                                &:first-child {
                                    margin-top: 0;
                                }

                                &__picture {
                                    inline-size: vw(47px);
                                    block-size: vw(47px);
                                    border-radius: 50%;

                                    background: {
                                        color: #1E2124;
                                        position: center;
                                        size: cover;
                                        repeat: no-repeat;
                                    }

                                }

                                .message-content {
                                    margin-left: vw(15px);

                                    &__text {
                                        &-nickname {
                                            @include font(ProximaNova, normal, normal, vw(17px));
                                            color: white;
                                        }

                                        &-date {
                                            @include font(ProximaNova, 100, normal, vw(13px));
                                            color: rgba(white, 0.5);
                                            margin-left: vw(10px);
                                        }

                                        &-message {
                                            @include font(ProximaNova, normal, normal, vw(17px));
                                            color: white;
                                            margin-top: vw(5px);
                                            margin-bottom: vw(20px);
                                            line-height: normal;
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }
```

[image: картинка 1][image: картинка 2]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если покажите кусок кода (HTML + CSS) в место картинок, поможем, если нет, топик будет прикрыт...

Comment: Отредактировал пост.

Comment: @MarkMinerov выложите код, вы опять сделали скриншоты, так сложно просто скопировать код со страницы?

Comment: У вас код на скришнотах понятен достаточно, тут vue.js, вы не сможете его взять и запустить просто так. Я показал на скриншотах основные моменты.

Comment: @MarkMinerov и что? vue подключается как то по особенному и его нельзя подключить?в редакторе кода

Comment: @MarkMinerov запускать ничего не надо.  Вам надо скопировать html код из браузера(то что сгенерировано через vue.js) и скопировать стили, которые отвечают за данный блок. Мы вам покажем пример корректной вёрстки(css) вы поймёте логику и сделаете тоже самое у себя.

Comment: В браузере это не повторить, этот баг происходит только в CEF, а он в GTA5.

Вёрстка некорректно работает только в нём, во всех остальных браузерах всё нормально.

Comment: По всей вероятности у вас баг в том, что родительский контейнер не "получает" высоту от потомков, установите родителю `display:inline-block;` или `overflow:hidden;` и всё.  А пример кода всегда желателен чтобы другим более понятно было.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` нельзя, мне нужно чтобы был scroll, там в коде прописано: `overflow: auto;`

Comment: Тем более, если вы хотите сделать скролл, тогда где же высота элемента?

Comment: У этого блока с сообщениями `height: 100%` и у него есть родитель, у которого прописано: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`, по этому этот блок всегда стремится занять как можно больше места, но не может сделать этого из-за других элементов в родителе, то есть занимает всё пустое пространство, которое осталось в родителе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, вложив расширяемый блок в простой `<div></div>`